# How to mock array of String

Tags: junit

below is the example code, if this work i can use the same logic in my business code.

```
class A{    
public String[] getString(String[] a){
    System.out.println("called");
    return a;
}}

class B{
A a;    
public String[] getString(){
    String[] ab = {"inside main class"};
    a= new A();
    return a.getString(ab);
}
}
```

Junit:

```
public class test{
private MockMvc mockMvc;
@Mock
private A a;

@InjectMocks
private B b;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(b).build();
}

@Test
public void test2Object(){
    String[] bc = {"mock main class"};      
    Mockito.when(a.getString(Mockito.any(String[].class))).thenReturn(bc);
    System.out.println((b.getString())[0]);
}   
}
```

Expected o/p "mock main class" but I am getting "inside main class"

Could anyone please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are injecting a Mock of A but in the B's getString method you are creating a new A instance and working on it. Remove it and the mocked version will be called:

```
class B{
   A a;    
   public String[] getString(){
      String[] ab = {"inside main class"};
      // a= new A();
      return a.getString(ab);
   }

   public void setA(A a){this.a = a;}
}
```

I would suggest adding a setter, so that in production you can inject that somehow.

**Update**

Your test class should like something like:

```
public class test{

   @Mock
   private A a;

   @InjectMocks
   private B b;

   @Before
   public void setUp() {
     MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
   }

   @Test
   public void test2Object(){
       // Arrange
       String[] bc = {"mock main class"};                                    
       Mockito.when(a.getString(Mockito.any(String[].class)))
               .thenReturn(bc);

       // Act
      String result = b.getString()[0];

      // Assert
      assertEquals(result, bc[0]);
   }   
}
```

Comment: Thank you, However, if I do with vefify i am getting error

Mockito.verify(a).getString(Mockito.any(String[].class));

error:"wanted but not invoked" but works fine when I use when

Comment: can you post the whole method?

Comment: @Test
 public void test2Object(){
  String[] bc = {"mock main class"};
  Mockito.verify(a).getString(Mockito.any(String[].class));
  System.out.println((b.getString())[0]);
 }

base Class
class B{
 A a; 
 public String[] getString(){
  String[] ab = {"inside main class"};
  String str = "";
  //a= new A();
  return a.getString(ab);
 }}

error
Wanted but not invoked:
a.getString(<any>);

Comment: could you pls let me know your suggestion to solve this issue

Comment: have added the test class that should work with your example.. You dont seem to need to use verify.. just straight assert. Hope it helps